# AWS CodeBuild Default Environment Variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, amazon-ecr

I'm having an issue while logging into ECR.

***buildspec.yml***

```
...
- echo $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION and $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID
- aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com
```

Following command return me "**us-east-2**" and "" (**$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID** is empty)

```
- echo $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION and $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID
```

so that's why I'm unable to login to ECR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is no default codebuild environment variable named `AWS_ACCOUNT_ID`

Here [Environment variables in build environments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-env-vars.html) you can find all default codebuild environment variables.

Comment: Is there any work around to get the account ID?

Comment: @Yougesh you can instrument something with [GetCallerIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetCallerIdentity.html) API call.

Comment: thanks for instruction, I have resolved by `$ aws sts get-caller-identity --query "Account" --output text`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @samtoddler, you can add this to your CloudFormation template, this will give you the output for **$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID** in the buildspec.yml

```
"EnvironmentVariables": [
                        {
                            "Name": "AWS_ACCOUNT_ID",
                            "Value": {
                                "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
```